# how to modify multiselect dropdown behaviour in already created survey using survey js-react

Tags: reactjs, surveyjs

Remove the option from the dropdown list if already selected and add again on removal from the selection or Disable option if already selected, enable again if deselected

Answer (score 0):

This feature is available with a multi-select Dropdown question: [Multi-Select Dropdown Box](https://surveyjs.io/form-library/examples/how-to-create-multiselect-tag-box/reactjs)
.

Enable the [hideSelectedItems](https://surveyjs.io/form-library/documentation/api-reference/dropdown-tag-box-model#hideSelectedItems) property to remove selected items from a drop-down list. Please test this example: https://plnkr.co/edit/EKPby7oYRBfKDWEc.

```
 {
     "type": "tagbox",
     "name": "question1",
     "title": "Which is the brand of your car?",
     "isRequired": true,
     "choices": [
      "Ford",
      "Vauxhall",
      "Volkswagen",
      "Nissan",
      "Audi",
      "Mercedes-Benz",
      "BMW",
      "Peugeot",
      "Toyota",
      "Citroen"
     ],
     "showOtherItem": true,
     "showNoneItem": true,
     "hideSelectedItems": true
    }
```